# Apache Flink same source stream writing to different sinks

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a `DataStream<Event> dataStream` and I'd like to have 2 `ProcessFunction` to process the same stream and write to 2 sinks respectively. I might have 2 options -

1. Use 2 process functions on the same stream directly -

```
dataStream.process(new ProcessFunction<Event, NewType1>()) // process function 1
dataStream.process(new ProcessFunction<Event, NewType2>()) // process function 2
```

2. Create separate streams using `SideOutput` and then use 2 Process Functions on these different streams

```
DataStream<Event> sideOutputStream1 = dataStream.getOutputTag(...) // tag 1
DataStream<Event> sideOutputStream2 = dataStream.getOutputTag(...) // tag 2
```

I was wondering which is the better approach here.

I tried both in dev environment, I am not sure what metrics I should be looking into to decide which approach to choose.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for side-outputs, except when you want some events to go in one stream and the other ones in a second stream.

I would go with the first option, just make sure that you create streams from both of them and consume them separately:

```
DataStream<Event> stream1 = dataStream.process(new ProcessFunction<Event, NewType1>()); 
DataStream<Event> stream2 = dataStream.process(new ProcessFunction<Event, NewType2>());

sink1.consume(stream1);
sink2.consume(stream2);
```

Comment: Thanks Flaviu! If we use the approach above, would Flink chain the 2 processors together? How does it work internally?

Comment: The 2 process functions will not be chained, they run in parallel.
To chain them you need to attach the second process function to `stream1` like this: 

`DataStream<Event> processedStream1 = stream1.process(new ProcessFunction<Event, NewType2>());`